# Image Stretching Only some Part

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to image stretching some portion  of image. Just below cutout off image. But when text increase it stretch full image. But i want to stretch a image after so.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgrKV.png)

```
balloonView.image =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatbg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:50 topCapHeight:0];;
```

Please check http://postimg.org/image/7d7lzu9n1/f99d1ebd/

Answer (score 0):

**General Discussion :** In order to create a stretchable `UIImage` in `iOS` like `9Patches` in android, you can use this:

```
UIImage * backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
backgroundImg = [backgroundImg resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,2, 2, 2)];
[imgView setImage:cellBackgroundImg];
```

you could also use:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth
                                 topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

> basically the image is not stretched in the area leftCapWidth pixels from the left and right edge and topCapHeight pixels from the top and the bottom. When the image is scaled the area inside of these limits is subject to stretching.

**OP's issue :** I think why you are not able to make it work is because your `topCapHeight` is set to `0`. try something like this :

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatbg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:50 
                                                        topCapHeight:50];
```

Comment: @sahim Thnks for reply . my image is strech as it content increase but its not work . when text is less it strech to minor and text getting increase its top portion also strech. Please help

Comment: @Vishiarora did you try setting `topCapHeight` to 50? also please post screenshot of the stretching, that will be helpful.

Comment: Yes i am setting  topCapHeight = 50, I am sending screen shot for a while

Comment: try setting the mode in the `UIImageView` to `Scale to fill` and set the Autoresize-property

Comment: @Vishiarora. also Create the file.png and file@2x.png file. Retina devices don't stretch when falling back to a non-retina bitmap

Comment: try both of the above and let me know if any of them does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A stretchable image is divided into 9 parts, if both leftCapWidth and topCapHeight are nonzero.

```
 leftCapWidth
  <----->
  +--------------+ ^
  |     | |      | |
  |  A  | |  B   | | topCapHeight
  |-----+·+------| v
  |-----+·+------|
  |  C  | |  D   |
  |     | |      |
  +--------------+
```

The central parts are always 1 px in size, and this is the part that is stretched, for example:

```
 leftCapWidth (constant!)
  <----->
  +------------------+ ^
  |     |     |      | |
  |  A  |     |  B   | | topCapHeight (constant!)
v |-----+ - - +------| v
| |     .     .      |
| |     .     .      |
^ |-----+ - - +------|
  |  C  |     |  D   |
  |     |     |      |
  +------------------+
        >-----<
    stretched region
```

Just use this code. If you have still any issue for left side arrow, then change the value of LeftCapWidth like 5,10,20 and then check it.

```
balloonView.image =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatbg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:20];
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me.